# Relative Image URL in Javascript File - ASP.net MVC and IIS 7

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am developing an Asp.net mvc application, everything works fine in ASP.net development server but when I am trying to host it on IIS 7. I am getting problem related to URL resolution. I have used relative paths in Javascript to give the image. The script file is in ~/Scripts/ folder and image files are in ~/Content/images/ folder. Now in the javascript file I am trying to use the give by giving the relative path like
http://localhost/WebApp1/controller1/action1/
it tries to find it at http://localhost/controller1/action1/ and couldn;t find the file.

Answer (score 4):

If how I'm reading this is correct, you're now running the WebApp from the domain root of IIS7 now instead of WebApp1 from your development environment?

So, if my assumption is correct, then ***~/*** should now resolve to ***http://localhost/*** instead of ***http://localhost/WebApp1/***

If that is all still correct, then your folder structure has all moved up one level with your ~/scripts folder in the absolute path:

http://localhost/Scripts/

and your images folder as:

http://localhost/Content/Images/

In order to access your images from your scripts, you can use a number of methods.  The simplest is to use the relative path from your scripts directory: *"../Content/Images/MyImage.jpg"*

Or you can use document.location.host to build the fully qualified path name within the javascript: *document.location.host + "/Content/Images/MyImage.jpg"*

Another method is to have ASP.NET build this part of the script dynamically so that the fully qualified path name is injected.You can do this by using *ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript* or *ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock*

There's really many ways to skin this cat, they're just the first 3 I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: +1 for option `document.location.host + "/Content/Images/MyImage.jpg"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

<a href="~/controller1/action1/" id="testLnk" runat="server">

The runat attribute should ensure that the framework resolves it. You can also use the ResolveUrl method.

Comment: I'm no JavaScript expert, but you could try embedding it like so:

<%= ResolveUrl("~/whatever.file") %>

Comment: I dont think it is possible to embed asp code like this into JS

Comment: @Raja, are you using master pages?

Answer (score 1):

I had and same problem and found an element solution by David Banister. The issue is with MVC controller's index action that returns a URL in the form of (www.mysite.com/viewName, as opposed to www.mysite.com/viewName/index) that the web browser later would fail when trying to reference css or js files using relative path syntax (../../).

His solution works well for me.  Hope this helps someone.  Good luck.

http://blog.davidbanister.com/2010/09/28/mvc-fixes-relative-path-issues-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past, try using tilde

> ~/controller1/action1/