# Correct way to referencing paths in a Javascript file in an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Currently what I'm doing in my js file is this (and it works):

```
    var root = "http://mydomain.com";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: root + "/MyController/MyAction",
    data: { 'id': myId },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
    blah blah...
```

However the problem is if someone types in www.mydomain.com instead of mydomain.com, the path is not found.  I tried following the advice in this post: [Relative Image URL in Javascript File - ASP.net MVC and IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342364/relative-image-url-in-javascript-file-asp-net-mvc-and-iis-7), namely setting root to ../ or document.location.host, but both don't work.

What's the correct way to specify paths (to actions in controllers, images, etc) in a js file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '<%= Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController") %>';
</script>
```

and in your external javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { 'id': postId },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
    blah blah...
```

or even better: if you are AJAXifying an existing link or form:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("foo", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { id = "foo" })
```

and in your javascript:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.href,
        data: { 'id': postId },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
        blah blah...
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have all my js code in an external javascript file and not embedded in the view, so I can't use <%= Url.Action.  That's the problem.

Comment: @Prabhu, that's why I started my answer with **In your view**.

Comment: I was going to say regular expression but this is obviously better.

Comment: Oh ok got it...so you're saying declare the url in the view and use it in the js file?  Not a bad idea actually.  Is this the standard way to do it?

Comment: @Prabhu, there are two possibilities: either you are AJAXifying an existing element of your DOM such as an anchor or a form in which case you already have the url in the DOM (see second part of my answer) or you don't in which case you could declare it as a global javascript variable.

Comment: I'm wondering now if I could also set the global variable url to the root domain in my masterpage--that way I won't have to change a bunch of code for now.  Do you think that's a good idea and if it's possible?

Comment: I like the solution. Consider using namespaces for your global variables like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration/881556#881556. Right now the variable url sits directly on window.

Comment: This declaration in the masterpage seems to do the trick: var root = '<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host %>';  Thanks!